# cgi program refuses to setuid root

Tags: linux, permissions, opensuse, opensuse-11.2

I have a C .cgi program that runs and mostly works. However, I need it to do some file manipulation, so I chown root & chmod +s the .cgi program:

```
-rwsr-sr-x 1 root root 59140 2015-07-20 13:39 sectl.cgi
```

When it runs, the program does not have the permissions it needs; a rename() command fails.
The output of the command

```
system("whoami");
```

is wwwrun. What's going on here?
(I'm certain I've done the same thing on other systems successfully)

openSUSE 11.2

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things to keep in mind:

- setuid for scripts is likely to be disabled (see *[Allow setuid on shell scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364/allow-setuid-on-shell-scripts)* for instance).
- even if your program is actually a *binary*, it is still possible that the file-system on which it resides is mounted with the [nosuid](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) option, or that SELinux prohibits the feature (see for example *[LD_PRELOAD with setuid binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232892/ld-preload-with-setuid-binary)*).

Comment: 1. It is a C program. 2. If I type "mount", I see nothing that looks like "nosuid". I do see acl. The getfacl shows nothing unexpected. The yast bootloader module does not have "enable selinux" checked, and man -k selinux returns nothing. I thought perhaps apache itself was doing the deed, but I see nothing in the config files about it (grep setuid)

Comment: SELinux is the likely culprit -- I would test with it disabled, just to verify that (and if so, do some reading to see how to appease it).

Comment: No SELinux that I could find, but I did find apparmor. Reboot, then `/etc/init.d/boot.apparmor stop` did not help, however. I didn't see a way to disable it completely.

Comment: Perhaps [aa-complain](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jaunty/man8/aa-complain.8.html) is the workaround (other than removing apparmor altogether).

Comment: I tried `aa-complain <cgi program>`, and I tried `aa-complain /usr/sbin/httpd2-1tk` Neither seemed to do any good. Am I missing something?

Comment: Your particular program does not have its own profile, but apparmor likely has profiles for more generic things such as apache.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26096/discussion-between-rich-and-thomas-dickey).

Comment: I can't comment in the chat window, unfortunately.

Comment: Anyway, I've had trouble finding out information about apparmor. I don't  know how to prove it's the culprit. I don't know whether it's apache or my .cgi that needs a profile. I tried aa-genprof on my .cgi program, but still no setuid. I found no documentation about apparmor controlling setuid. I'm going to give up and reinstall linux on the computer in question.